# Simplest method of enforcing HTTPS for Heroku Ruby Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, redirect, heroku, https, sinatra

I have an app I created on Heroku which is written in Ruby (not rails) and Sinatra.
It is hosted on the default herokuapp domain so I can address the app with both HTTP and HTTPS.
The app requests user credentials which I forward on to an HTTPS call so the forwarding part is secure.
I want to ensure my users always connect securely to my app so the credentials aren't passed in clear text.

Despite lots of research, I've not found a solution to this simple requirement.

Is there a simple solution without changing my app to Ruby rails or otherwise?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Are you sure you did a lot of research ?? This should help - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'd already read that and I don't see how it helps.  The article describes how to enable SSL on a custom domain but  as I stated my app runs on the herokuapp domain.  If I missed something which describes how to enforce HTTPS please point out.  The proposed answer by CodeGnome below works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I use a helper that looks like this:

```
def https_required!
    if settings.production? && request.scheme == 'http'
        headers['Location'] = request.url.sub('http', 'https')
        halt 301, "https required\n"
    end
end
```

I can then add it to any single route I want to force to https, or use it in the `before` filter to force on a set of urls:

```
before "/admin/*" do
    https_required!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Redirect in a Before Filter

This is untested, but it should work. If not, or if it needs additional refinement, it should at least give you a reasonable starting point.

```
before do
  redirect request.url.sub('http', 'https') unless request.secure?
end
```

#### See Also

- [Filters](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters)
- [Request Object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object)
- [RackSsl::Enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer)